# como subir una imagen desde php sin formulario

Tags: php, mysql, php5

```
        //conexion a la base de datos
        include ("DAL/conexion.php");
        include ("generarCadena.php");
        //cargtamos la libreria para generar el QR
        require_once('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

        function generarQR(){
        //directorio donde se guardara la imagen
            $dir='temp/';
        if(!file_exists($dir))
            //en caso de que no exista la carpeta la creamos con mkdir
            mkdir($dir);
            //pasamos la ruta de la imagen
            $filename=$dir.'prueba.png';
            $nombreimg='prueba.png';
            //configuracion del codigo QR
            $size=5;    //Tamanio de la imagen que se creara
            $level='L'; //precicion del codigo que tan definido se vera, puede ser L, Q, H
            $frameSize=3;   //tamaño del marco del qr   
            $content= generarCadena();  //contenido, mandamos a llamar al metodo que genera cadenas
            echo 'Contenido del QR: '.$content;
            echo '<br>';
            QRcode::png($content,$filename,$level,$size,$frameSize);
            echo '<img src="'.$filename.'"/>';
            move_uploaded_file($filename, $dir);
            $bytes=file_get_contents($filename);
            guardarQR($content,$bytes);    
        }
        function guardarQR($archivo,$contenido){
            $sentencia="insert into usuarioportador (QR,foto) values('$contenido','$archivo');";
            echo $sentencia;
            ejecutar($sentencia);
        }
        generarQR();
```

Comment: sin formulario? 
automaticamente dices?

Comment: Si, género un código QR y lo almacenó en una carpeta del servidor pero requiero de guardarla en un formato blob en MySQL , el problema es que no he hayado la manera de ocupar la imagen sin un form